# How to pass data from a JTextField to another JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I need to pass a text from a JTextField in a JFrame to a second JTextField in another JFrame. GUI has been created using GUI Editor netbeans 6.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [textField.getText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) to get the text from a textfield and [anotherTextField.setText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) to set the text of the other textfield.

If your JFrames are in two different classes you may have to expose methods in those classes to get and set the text between them.

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't use a GUI Editor, especially if you are just learning Swing.
2. You need a reference saved somewhere to both fields so that you `getText()` of the first JTextField and `setText()` on the second field.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your model to both of the views (JTextFields) instead of copying Text from one to another.

Read http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/OrganizingPresentations.html for more information.